# How to re-create media file from android sender output stream

Tags: android, dynamic-analysis, networking

I would like to perform dynamic analysis on some android apps to check if these apps sending metadata with media files or not.

Ideas like the picture below:

**Step 1**: I prepared an image with metadata (location, time, etc.)

**Step 2**: I use an Android app to send the images on Step-1 and try to capture the sender bytes stream.

**Step 3**: Re-create the image from the bytes stream and check metadata.

I don't have much experience as a reverse engineer so please help me with some ideas or useful tools.

Thank you.
[image]

Comment: I would recommend a rooted device, and mproxy for intercepting the communication. For installing the mproxy root CA certificate you need root permissions as described here https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/howto-install-system-trusted-ca-android/

Comment: @Robert. thank you. I will test now.